# How to check condition for nullable boolean type?

Tags: c#, linq

I have written a query which is returning `bool?`.

```
var query=
    (from der in Context.DealEntityRights
    join drule in Context.DealEntityRightsRule
        on der.EntityRightsID equals drule.DealEntityRights.EntityRightsID 
    where der.PlatformID == item.PlatformID
    select drule).Distinct().Select(a => a.HasRights);
```

`HasRights` has type `bool?`

Now I have to check the condition in an `if` statement, so I have written:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(query))
{
    ...
}
```

But it's throwing an exception.  I tried `if (query.value == true)` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: The query is not returning `bool?` but a collection of `bool?`

Comment: "it's throwing exception" and "its showing error" - why haven't you told us what these errors are? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list - also, please pay more attention to your formatting.

Comment: query returns a collection , not a single boolean

Comment: I really wish you guys wouldn't be so quick to approve incomplete edit suggestions... there was so much more that needed fixing...

Comment: Its returning collection. its working fine.. Thanks nphx, Shai :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a filter for only the results which have values:

```
...Select(a=>a.HasRights).Where(a => a.HasValue);
```